# Attempt to read property "status" on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

First time i try to log in in my website the website crash with error " status on null" , sometimes when i refresh it lets . I cant find the error.

```php
public function authenticate()
{
        $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();
        if (!Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }

        $user = $this->user();
        $customer = $user->customer;
        if ($customer->status !== CustomerStatus::Active->value) { 

            /*the problem is here*/
            Auth::guard('web')->logout();

            $this->session()->invalidate();
            $this->session()->regenerateToken();
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => 'Your account has been disabled',
            ]);
        }

        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
    }
```

Here is the customer status,

```
enum CustomerStatus: string
{
    case Active = 'active';
    case Disabled = 'disabled';
}
```

There ary many errors like this in my project , i tried this :

`if ($customer->status ?? '' !== CustomerStatus::Active->value)`

But then I cant log in , all my accounts become disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `$customer` variable is `null` before accessing its status property.

```
if (!$customer || $customer->status !== CustomerStatus::Active->value) { 
    // handle disabled account
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```php
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();
    if (!Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    $user = $this->user();
    $customer = $user->customer;

    if ($customer->status !== CustomerStatus::Active->value && $customer->status != null) {
        /*the problem is here*/
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();

        $this->session()->invalidate();
        $this->session()->regenerateToken();
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
           'email' => 'Your account has been disabled',
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

Comment: You can use this code if status == null

Comment: No , same problem .